# The question mark syntax to retrieve final property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out if these two expressions are functionally equivalent:

```
user && user.first_name ? user.first_name : ''
```

and

```
user?.first_name || ''
```

and fairly certain they are, but not 100% sure. Are there any cases where the two expressions differ?

Comment: I believe so, unless I'm also missing something as well. I usually do something like `user?.first_name ?? ''` instead of using `||` though

Comment: ahh what is the double ?? vs || ?

Comment: Nullish coalescing operator. Returns right-side if left-side is null or undefined, otherwise returns left-side

Comment: @rakim `||` if you want to check for [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) is for nullish (only null and undefined)

Comment: thanks, that's pretty good info